# how to use asutime limit for stored proc?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

we need to limit for how long a stored proc can run, currently we check the current timestamp against the input parameter timestamp for process to end. but has anyone used asutime limit and what are its effects/advantages?

Comment: yes it is db2. any ideas? i want to know how db2 runs the proc with asutime limit in place.

Comment: Which platform?  ASUTIME has no effect for DB2 LUW.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready feature for this on LUW, at least for 9.7 and below. However, you can attempt to query externally for the long-running queries

```
SELECT SUBSTR(STMT_TEXT, 1, 50) AS STMT_TEXT, AGENT_ID, 
   ELAPSED_TIME_MIN, APPL_STATUS, DBPARTITIONNUM 
   FROM SYSIBMADM.LONG_RUNNING_SQL ORDER BY DBPARTITIONNUM
```

and take a look at the ELAPSED_TIME_MIN and for instance STMT_TEXT to figure out what application to kill. You have to run your logic against the database on regular intervals to kill ("force application") the long-running applications.